# Looking for a pressure phase diagram of selenium at large ranges of pressure and temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, molecular-structure, phase

I'm doing undergraduate research and our group is having a lot of difficulty finding a comprehensive pressure phase diagram or phase table for selenium (including most known packing geometries that are known at extremely high pressures).

I figured I may ask here as we've spend a while searching and haven't turned up so much as a good lead for where this information may be documented. Furthermore, we'd like to know where to look from now on to find information like this (such as a similar chart for sulfur? Albeit we haven't spent as much time looking for this as it's not of our particular research interest).

Comment: 1. Young, D. A. Phase Diagrams of the Elements; *University of California Press*, **1991**; 2. Olin, A., Mompean, F. J., Eds.; Chemical Thermodynamics of Selenium; *Elsevier: Amsterdam*, **2005**.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437103000116) is a computational study that computes the phase diagram of selenium and sulfur. They reference an [experimental paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960191900438) that looks at this, but you might not be able to access that one.